# VBA - Inserting a space between concatenated cells

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

This code works for me. However, in the destination cell, I'd like a space between A2 and B2's values:

```
For j = 1 To lastRow3
    If ws.Range("A" & j) = "OKUMA LATHE" Then
        Cells(j, lastCol2 + 2).Formula = "=$A2&$B2"
    End If
Next j
```

What's a boy to do? Everything I try gives me a compile error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to double up the quotes in VBA

```
For j = 1 To lastRow3
    If ws.Range("A" & j) = "OKUMA LATHE" Then
        Cells(j, lastCol2 + 2).Formula ="=$A2 & "" "" & $B2"
    End If
Next j
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I hadn't tried that... I ran through ALOT of quote and ampersand combinations.